# Can't login a just-created user, in a Django test

Tags: python, django

In a Django testing class, `self.client.login(...)` is returning `False`, and I don't understand why. This is the testing module

```
"""Tests for views."""
from django.contrib.auth.models             import User
from .models                                import UserProfile
from django.test                            import TestCase

TEST_USER = {"username":   "kermit", "password":  "timrek",
             "first_name": "Kermit", "last_name": "The Frog",
             "birth_year": 1955,     "email":     "kermit@muppets.com"}

class ViewTestCase(TestCase):
    """Tests for views."""
    def setUp(self_ignored):
        """Insert demo users."""

        user = User(
            username=TEST_USER['username'], password=TEST_USER['password'],
            first_name=TEST_USER['first_name'],
            last_name=TEST_USER['last_name'], email=TEST_USER['email'])
        user.save()

        profile = UserProfile(user_id=user.id,
                              birth_year=TEST_USER['birth_year'])
        profile.save()
```

The function that attempts to log the user in (this is the bottom portion of the same file):

```
    def test__view_for_logged_in_user(self):
        """Verify expected content on the main birth-stats page, for a
            logged-in user.
       """

        print("TEST_USER=" + TEST_USER)

        did_login_succeed = self.client.login(
            username=TEST_USER['username'],
            password=TEST_USER['password'])

        #print the just inserted users
        users = User.objects.all()
        print("Total users actually in the database=" + str(users.count()))
        for  user in users:
            print('Actually-inserted user: ' + str(user))

        self.assertTrue(did_login_succeed)     #Fails

        #test view here
```

As you can see in the debugging output, the test user is indeed being inserted:

```
$ python manage.py test auth_lifecycle.test__views2
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
TEST_USER={'username': 'kermit', 'email': 'kermit@muppets.com', 'password': 'timrek', 'birth_year': 1955, 'last_name': 'The Frog', 'first_name': 'Kermit'}
Total users actually in the database=1
Actually-inserted user: kermit
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test__view_for_logged_in_user (auth_lifecycle.test__views2.ViewTestCase)
Verify expected content on the main birth-stats page, for a
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/auth_lifecycle/test__views2.py", line 47, in test__view_for_logged_in_user
    self.assertTrue(did_login_succeed)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.009s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Why is this login failing (returning False)?

---

Here's the model

```
"""Defines a single extra user-profile field for the user-authentication
    lifecycle demo project: Birth year.
"""
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db                  import models

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """One piece of extra information about a user: Birth year.

        ---NOTES---

        Useful related SQL:
            - `select id from auth_user where username <> 'admin';`
            - `select * from auth_lifecycle_userprofile where user_id=(x,x,...);`
    """
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")

    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    birth_year = models.IntegerField(
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="Year you were born")

    # Override the __str__() method to return out something meaningful
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although

```
user = User(
    username=TEST_USER['username'], password=TEST_USER['password'],
    first_name=TEST_USER['first_name'],
    last_name=TEST_USER['last_name'], email=TEST_USER['email'])
user.save()
```

saves the user to the database, the password is not properly hashed and salted (I'm think that's the problem). Therefore, attempting to login with that same password fails (`login` returns `False`).

```
self.client.login(
    username=TEST_USER['username'],
    password=TEST_USER['password'])  #Not the same as in the database!
```

The solution is to use the [`create_user` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) instead:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(
    username=TEST_USER['username'], password=TEST_USER['password'],
    first_name=TEST_USER['first_name'],
    last_name=TEST_USER['last_name'], email=TEST_USER['email'])
```